# border around button in html file in internet explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am working on html file at [www.bookmyshirt.co.cc/hair/city.html](http://www.bookmyshirt.co.cc/hair/city.html) 
on this page there is border around button "find out more city" in IE but it perfext on firefox.
How i remove that border ?

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your stylesheet:

```
a img { border: none; }
```